# compare variable and string in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to compare the status of a variable "feedback" against a string '*Not Available*'.

I'm able to console.log the value of the variable and it displays *Not Available*, yet, If statement logic is not displaying "username already in use"

```
var feedback = $("#feedback").text();
console.log("feedback status is:" + feedback);
if (feedback === 'Not Available') {
    console.log("Username already in use!");
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: First of all the `e.preventDefault()` is wrong. What supposed that does ? And can you please provide us with the exact output of the `console.log` ?

Comment: How about posting a *complete* code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be your variable value contains extra spaces, try using [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/), as:

```
if ( $.trim(feedback) === 'Not Available' ) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use localeCompare()

```
if (feedback.localeCompare('Not Available')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Please show your console result.So we can get idea of actually what getting from your variable.

Try variableName. toLowerCase()  to remove case sensitive issues.